# Which image loading method should i prefer?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, sdwebimage

I have app with TableView and cells. In each cell there is UIImageView.
All images are stored on server.

I can use two different methods to load images. Which of them should prefer and why?

**Method A** : 
Use library like SDWebImage to load image and place it in cellForRowAtIndexPath function. So image will be downloaded when cell is created.

**Method B** : 
When i load JSON with image list from server i can create array of UIImages. In each of them i will asynchronously download image from server. And in cellForRowAtIndexPath function i can just assign one of previously created UIImages to current cell image.

Comment: It depends a little on how many images there are, but method a is probably the best

Comment: I load 20-40 images, can you explain - why this method is better?

Comment: Then definitely method A. You will get caching and you will avoid loading images if the user doesn't scroll to them

Answer (score 1):

Method A - SDWebimage is best for you.

and solve reuse in tableviewcell  check this link : [Handling download of image using SDWebImage while reusing UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23818055/handling-download-of-image-using-sdwebimage-while-reusing-uitableviewcell)

Answer (score 1):

Don't ever use method 2 to handle Images in your application. This is a data and memory wise expensive method. To the best of my understanding, this method would extensively increase the memory pressure. If you create an array of images that would remain in the memory as long as your view controller stays. As the size of this array increases the situation will get worse.

`SDWebImage` is far far better approach for this task. It saves the images to local storage once downloaded thus creating a cache of images. So you do not have to download the images again and again.

Answer (score 0):

i wish to use AFNetworking if you don't need to  cache image , this tools  faster than SDWebImage when load image from server . //////

if you use custom cell => replace UITableViewCell with your name file for cell

```
-(void)fetchImageFromURL:(NSString*)imageURLString Cell:(UITableViewCell*)cell {

    /*
     _ This Function will accept the string url for Image
     _ Also  the cell that have image icon
     _ After take paramter will make request to fetch image
     _  
        1- if return image => will show Image

    */
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", imageURLString]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];


    __weak UITableViewCell *weakCell = cell;
    // get image with request
    [[cell imageView ] setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:nil
                                   success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
                                       [[weakCell ImageIcon ] setImage:image];
                                       [weakCell setNeedsLayout];
                                   }

                                   failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                       NSLog(@"couldn't load image with url :%@", url);
                                   }];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best choice in my opinion is to rely on a stable, fresh, followed and secure framework.

Recently come to the scene a great framework written in Swift called [Nuke](https://github.com/kean/Nuke)  (**Swift 3 - Xcode 8**) . I think you could try Nuke, his power is the "preheat images" (preheating/prefetching means loading images ahead of time in anticipation of its use.), it's full compatible with Alamofire , already knowed by community ([raywenderlich.com](https://www.raywenderlich.com/118361/what-is-nuke)) and now is at v.4.x (stable and mature). This library have custom handlers and requests with many options.

Comment: thank you, but i am asking about where should I use image loading. Also this framework can be good and fresh but it needs at least iOS 9.0. My app is working on iOS 7 with SDWebImage.

Comment: You're welcome, you have to choose the best for your project. Your question is tagged with SWIFT only and don't report iOS limitation so I've tried to advise the most suitable product. Good luck for your work.